# Подсчет максимального, минимального, среднего арифметического и медианы ОГРОМНОГО количества чисел в .txt файле

Tags: алгоритм, числа

Есть файл, содержащий большой набор целых чисел - набор чисел в .txt файле (файл вы можете скачать [здесь](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxJCrRlrnGOUelo3VlNUM3hwZE0/view)).

Задача состоит в том, чтобы найти следующие четыре величины:

1. максимальное число в файле;
2. минимальное число в файле;
3. [медиану](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0));
4. [среднее арифметическое значение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5).

Необходимо найти абсолютно любой способ выполнения данной задачи, предложенный метод решения должен находить все четыре величины из данного файла не более чем за 90 секунд. (Это условие необязательно, однако будет существенным плюсом, если ваше решение будет ему удовлетворять).

Можно, например, написать программу причём на любом известном вам языке программирования. Или использовать существующие программы\утилиты.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

На C#:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp58
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var numbers = File.ReadLines(@"C:\temp\File\10m.txt").AsParallel().Select(Int32.Parse).OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(numbers.Last());
            Console.WriteLine(numbers.First());

            var mid = numbers.Count / 2;
            Console.WriteLine((numbers.Count % 2 == 0) ? (numbers[mid] + numbers[mid - 1]) / 2 : numbers[mid]);

            Console.WriteLine(numbers.Average());
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
49999978
-49999996
25216
7364.41844264184
2255
```

Последнее число - время работы в миллисекундах.

Comment: Том Сойер тоже умел заставить забор за себя красить ;)

Comment: Зачем ReadAllLines, когда можно было лениво ReadLines?

Comment: @AK ага. еще докинул распараллеливания, зря я что ли себе i7 купил. Надо будет еще SSD взять на M2.

Comment: @MBo просто сдать такое как "алгоритм" не получится :)

Comment: `OrderBy` и `ToList` плохо сочетаются с условием "ОГРОМНОГО количества чисел"

Comment: @PashaPash огромное спасибо за оперативную помощь в решении данной задачи! Рад, что данный вопрос вызвал интерес!

Answer (score 1):

На php (7.2)

```
<?php
// Чтение из файла в массив
$digitsArray = file('10m.txt');

// чистка от "\n" и преобразование строк в число
$digitsArray = array_map( function ($item) {
    return (int)trim($item);
}, $digitsArray);

// сортировка массива по возрастанию
sort($digitsArray, SORT_NUMERIC);

// сумма всех элементов
$sum = array_sum($digitsArray);

// количество элементов
$count = count($digitsArray);

// среднее арифметическое
$arithmeticMean = $sum / $count;

// минимальное число
$min = $digitsArray[0];

// максимальное число
$max = end($digitsArray);

// медиана
if($count % 2 === 0) {
    $median = ($digitsArray[$count / 2] + $digitsArray[$count / 2 - 1]) / 2;
} else {
    $median = $digitsArray[intdiv($count, 2)];
}

print_r([
    'min' => $min,
    'max' => $max,
    'sum' => $sum,
    'arithmeticMean' => $arithmeticMean,
    'median' => $median
]);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [min] => -49999996
    [max] => 49999978
    [sum] => 73644177062
    [arithmeticMean] => 7364.4184426418
    [median] => 25216
)
```

Comment: огромное спасибо за помощь и альтернативное быстрое решение задачи!

Answer (score 0):

О, никак кодогольф :) Ну, тогда С++, который позволяет обойтись без полной сортировки :)

```
int main()
{
    ifstream in("10m.txt");
    vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(10000000);
    copy(istream_iterator<int>(in),istream_iterator<int>(),back_inserter(v));
    auto [m,M] = minmax_element(v.begin(),v.end());
    cout << "Min: " << *m << "\nMax: " << *M << "\nAvg: " << setprecision(8)
         << accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0ll)/double(v.size());
    nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size()/2, v.end());
    cout << "\nMed: " << v[v.size()/2] << "\n";
}
```

Ясно, что результаты те же:

```
Min: -49999996
Max: 49999978
Avg: 7364.4184
Med: 25216
```

А время - так оно полностью определяется диском. У меня - 5.3с.

P.S. И разве это - *огромное* количество?...

P.P.S. Интереса ради вычислял минимальное, максимальное и среднее прямо по ходу чтения - дало выигрыш всего лишь примерно 40 мс. Из всего времени работы программы чтение файла, как и следовало ожидать, занимает более 98%.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь в решении данной задачи!
Понятия "огромного" очень относительное, для меня количество чисел показалось действительно огромным :)